# Python rsa экспорт и импорт

Tags: python, rsa

Нужно импортировать-экспортировать ключи в файл. Пользуюсь модулем rsa (import rsa). Не могу понять где документацию по нему почитать? Интересует работа именно с этим модулем

Comment: Если Вас интересует конкретно импорт\экспорт ключей в файл, то Вам не по библиотеке маны читать, а по файловому вводу\выводу :)

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html) почитайте!

Так же связный вопрос на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327491/using-pycrypto-how-to-import-a-rsa-public-key-and-use-it-to-encrypt-a-string - где вы наверняка найдёте решение вашей проблемы!

Всё на онглицком!

Comment: Кажется, это другая библиотека.

Comment: да. наверное ...